# Exporting vector layer to kml

Tags: qgis, kml, export

I'm having difficulty exporting a vector file of polygons (UK ward boundaries) in QGIS to kml format.  The error I get is:

```
'OGR error - failed to create kml file'.
```

Maybe I am getting the field names mixed up - I need the ward code to identify each polygon (a string beginning with E)- should this be the 'name' field in the export field to kml?  And what should be the 'description' field?  Although I notice in one kml file in the attribute table, all the polygons are listed but there are no labels or data attached to any of them.

Comment: I found a work around to this, based on a posting by Artwork21?  'create new point layer from polygon layer and in the save vector layer as dialog define the labelling field in the Namefield textbox.  Once you have both kml created in GE, select File Open to add both kml in'.  It is this latter point that I am having trouble understanding - what is GE, and how do I add both kml files in?